# MAC Address to Location - available services

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, mac-address

I am having a set of MAC addresses, and I would like to determine a location against the same. 
I am aware of Google, HERE and SkyHook providing geo-location APIs with which it would be possible to provide the MAC addresses and possibly obtain a location. 
My question here is, is anybody in the community using any alternative service in addition to the ones listed above, for the same purpose?